# Google Pixel Watch 2 accessory mode (Pyusb)

Tags: python, android, wear-os, pyusb

I used these docs https://source.android.com/docs/core/interaction/accessories/aoa and pyusb to send the required control requests to my Pixel Watch 2, from my PC. If i do so, my Watch displays a notification stating: "USB accessory connected" and displaying a Button stating "Open on watch". If i click the button nothing happens.
I'm currently trying to connect an ESP32 to a Pixel Watch 2 over its 4 Pin connector.